# Fit ten horses in nine boxes

Tags: logical-deduction

Here is my puzzle:

How can you fit ten horses in nine boxes?

Here are the boxes:
[image]

Rules:

- All boxes must be filled
- No additional boxes can be created

Good luck :)

Comment: Does one box can only contains one horse?

Comment: That's what I was about to ask

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: @NSPredator Should all the horses be alive?

Comment: Easy, you chop one of the horses into 9 equal pieces and put one-and-a-ninth horses in each box.

Answer (score 8):

> Put 8 male horses to first 8 box and put a pregnant female horse to last room.

Comment: This would be a fantastic answer if the question had the 'lateral-thinking' tab!

Comment: @shyos why not 9 pregnant horses and say you have put 18 horses in 9 boxes. ;-)

Comment: why not 36, and all 9 are having triplets?  :) (although, after googling, it is so rare that triplet births in horses have never once been known to result in 3 surviving babies, and twins is also rare and usually ends in deaths)

Comment: @JLee well, there is no ruls on the question indicates that horses cant be dead, still counts :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is my answer:

> You can place the 9 letters of "ten horses" in the boxes:
>  T E N H O R S E S

Answer (score 3):

The expected answer:

> |1 | 2 |3 | 4 | 5 |6 | 7 |8 | 9 |
>
>  [T][E][N][H][O][R][S][E][S]

Now the real challenge is to make up new valid answers..

Alternate answers:

> Remove the walls between the boxes to and add them to the end to end up with just 1 longer box, then insert all the horses into the 1 box. (Can now store up to 10-13 horses!)
>
>  Assuming they are toy horses, and grind them up. You can now fit the maximum possible horses into the boxes. (Much greater than 10)

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously, this. I can't think anything else really.
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

My idea:

> If you order the boxes like this:
>
> `+---+---+---+---+
> | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
> +---+---+---+---+
> | 5 |       | 6 |
> +---+---+---+---+
> | 7 | 8 | 9 |////
> +---+---+---+////`
>
>  you get a spot in the middle that is no box but yet big enough for the tenth horse, and you can get to it by moving box 6 to the shaded zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can double up one of the boxes because these 9 boxes make up the bigger box (box of boxes). You didn't say only 1 horse per box.